# TableView Enhancements

Tags: javafx, tableview

The TableView still leaves a lot to be desired. Does anyone have a more complex example of a TableView that you would like to share? Here's what I'm missing:

- Insert and Delete row:
  Possible solutions:

  - press TAB on the last cell and new row gets inserted automatically
  - right mouse button -> context menu -> insert line (or delete line)
  - a table footer with table navigation and insert/delete buttons (like MS Access)
  - keyboard shortcut
  - ...

  Insert and Delete should be either at the current row position or at the bottom of the table. Of course the new row should be highlighted.
- Copying / Duplication of rows inside the TableView
- Copy selected cells to the clipboard

  (solution exists: [copy multiple cells to clipboard](https://gist.github.com/Lofi007/3064b5bb162d5cbc795a), paste into table is missing)
- Insert a row with default values
- Type to Edit: I don't want to have to doubleclick on a cell first in order to edit it. When you type on a cell, the table should automatically go into edit mode.
- Navigation options like e. g. TAB = cell in next column, ENTER = cell in next row
- Filtering should be possible via components inside the tableview, not via components (TextField etc) outside of it. A filter indicator (like the sort indicator) would be nice.
- Changing the visibility of columns should be convenient, not via multiple clicks of the tableview menu button (for every column you have to click the menu button separately to show the available columns). The tableview menu button should be customizable

  (solutions exist [with reflection](https://gist.github.com/Lofi007/f089394a444d449a6ff2) and [without reflection](https://gist.github.com/Lofi007/113a7f4cd3f793028f4e))
- Row and column headers should be possible
- Validation of cells, so that when you are in edit mode and enter text instead of digits into a numeric cell you get the option to cancel the edit mode and revert to the default value
- A (fixed) table footer which could e. g. show the sum for each column would be nice
- Freezing of columns (there's already a Jira task for this)

Some of these were covered partially years ago from what I've seen. But I couldn't get a clear How-To impression and maybe things have changed with JavaFX8.

In case someone likes to contribute to any of these mentioned features, please share your thoughts. Thank you very much.

Comment: This sounds like a different use case than the standard `TableView` is intended to address. Does the [`SpreadsheetView` from ControlsFX](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/index.html?org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html) meet your requirements better?

Comment: Thank you, I've already checked that out. Unfortunately it seems to be in experimental state and hence it's buggy. Besides I'm afraid it goes the SwingX way and becomes too interwoven with the rest of the components. And simply putting a SpreadsheetView on a BorderPane showed that it needs a lot of polishing (First column is cut off, horizontal Scrollbar is wrong, etc). I'll use it to check out how they did things. However, bugs aside, it lacks 1 major feature that a user requires from a table: Inserting and Deleting rows via user interaction.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [Panemu's TiwulFX 2](http://tiwulfx.panemu.com) and see if it can be adopted for your use case - it's not exactly what you describe but seems a lot closer to your specification than a standard JavaFX TableView.  Or perhaps embed a googledocs spreadsheet in a WebView.  Regardless, I don't think your question can be reasonably answered in a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: It seems closer to what I want, but it is really slow and buggy. I'll try to implement the required code myself and provide separate gists for every item. By the way, thanks a lot for your gists, they are a very good inspiration! Do you suggest closing the question? Because it's not a single question, it's rather a multitude of questions packaged in 1 question.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: You mean I should close it and create 12 separate questions?