# Insertion TableView JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Never crossed my mind until i was showing someone a working(ish) prototype. They asked if it possible to add a new row to a tableview above a current one i.e. Excel.

The application in question is generating travel itineries so if someone forgets to type one specific leg of a journey they would at the moment have to delete the following rows and continue as normal (bit of a pain).

Doing some searching on Google hasn't really helped its just pointing to adding a new row after the previous ones, can this be done.

Example:

```
    04FEB London to New York
    --> insert here (forgot new york to san fran).
    23FEB San Francisco to New York
    23FEB New York to London
```

Many Thanks

Comment: You are asking how to insert row to TableView in JavaFX? 
You can be more specific?

Comment: Rows in tables are nothing more than data in an `ObservableList` which is set as items in it. If you change the list, the items/rows in the Table changes.

Comment: All you have to do is insert s new item into the table's item list at the appropriate index. Can you be more specific about what action you want the user to take to insert the new row?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's possible by modification of the data list.

Comment: What do you mean "not supported out of the box?"  All you need is `table.getItems().add(index, new Item());`

Comment: Customers want inline editing. Nobody wants to edit a table like in [this example with external controls](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm). If you show that to a user they laugh at you and say "no, thanks".

Comment: The OP said nothing about the editing behavior they wanted, but then all you need is to call `table.edit(...)`

Comment: The OP wrote "i.e. Excel".

Comment: In Excel, I do that from a menu item. So the implementation is trivial, no?

Comment: Depends, [various solutions are possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27814811/tableview-enhancements) (first bullet point). I've wanted to do it myself, but didn't get to it yet and other things, e. g. when you type you'd want to be in the edit mode. However there was (or still is) e. g. a bug with the focus lost event and all you typed was gone etc. And of course when you append or insert a line, you'd want to scroll to it and highlight it. But there was also [something off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714267/how-to-correctly-add-new-data-to-tableview-and-scroll-to-it).

Comment: All completely off topic. Not every SO question about `TableView` is an excuse for you to complain that it's not a spreadsheet - it was never intended to be such and clearly for this use case a model-specific table is more appropriate than a spreadsheet. `TableView` is not perfect, obviously; for example not committing on focus lost is accepted as a mistake and is in the process of being fixed for the next release. But the functionality the OP is asking for in this case is easily supported and has nothing to do with the objections you raise.

Comment: I didn't say it should be a spreadsheat, but at least it should support core functionality like inserting a row, highlighting the new row, etc. And regarding the focus lost bug (which is an important thing if you consider entering data and not losing it important): How long has it not been fixed? And it won't until Java 9.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially all you need to do is insert a new item into the table's items list at the appropriate location:

```
table.getItems().add(index, newItem);
```

You can add some user functionality, such as starting an edit on the new item, or making a best-guess initialization of the data depending on the surrounding data if you need.

Here's a very quick (15 mins total coding, so obviously it probably includes some bugs) example: I put the "insert row before" and "insert row after" functionality into a context menu on the table rows, but obviously you can hook it to any user action you want.

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ItineraryBuilder extends Application {

    private TableView<ItineraryLeg> table;

    private void insert(int rowIndex, String origin, String destination, int editCol) {
        table.getItems().add(rowIndex, new ItineraryLeg(origin, destination));
        table.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(rowIndex);
        table.edit(rowIndex, table.getColumns().get(editCol));
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);

        table.getColumns().add(column("Origin", ItineraryLeg::originProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Destination", ItineraryLeg::destinationProperty));

        table.getItems().addAll(
                new ItineraryLeg("London","New York"),
                new ItineraryLeg("San Francisco","New York"),
                new ItineraryLeg("New York", "London"));


        table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<ItineraryLeg> row = new TableRow<>();
            MenuItem addBefore = new MenuItem("Insert leg before");
            MenuItem addAfter = new MenuItem("Insert leg after");
            ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu(addBefore, addAfter);
            addBefore.setOnAction(e -> {
                String origin = row.getIndex() == 0 ? "" : table.getItems().get(row.getIndex()-1).getDestination();
                String destination = table.getItems().get(row.getIndex()).getOrigin() ;
                insert(row.getIndex(), origin, destination, 0);
            });
            addAfter.setOnAction(e -> {
                String origin = table.getItems().get(row.getIndex()).getDestination();
                String destination = row.getIndex() == table.getItems().size()-1 
                        ? "" 
                        : table.getItems().get(row.getIndex()+1).getOrigin() ;
                insert(row.getIndex()+1, origin, destination, 1);
            });
            row.contextMenuProperty().bind(
                    Bindings.when(row.emptyProperty())
                    .then((ContextMenu)null)
                    .otherwise(menu));
            return row ;
        });

        Label label = new Label("Build Itinerary");
        Button add = new Button("Add leg");
        HBox controls = new HBox(5, label, add);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        add.setOnAction(e -> insert(table.getItems().size(), "Origin", "Destination", 0));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        root.setTop(controls);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private static <S> TableColumn<S,String> column(String title, Function<S, StringProperty> property) {
        TableColumn<S,String> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        col.setPrefWidth(200);
        return col ;
    }

    public static class ItineraryLeg {
        private final StringProperty origin = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty destination = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public ItineraryLeg(String origin, String destination) {
            setOrigin(origin);
            setDestination(destination);
        }

        public final StringProperty originProperty() {
            return this.origin;
        }


        public final String getOrigin() {
            return this.originProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setOrigin(final String origin) {
            this.originProperty().set(origin);
        }


        public final StringProperty destinationProperty() {
            return this.destination;
        }


        public final String getDestination() {
            return this.destinationProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setDestination(final String destination) {
            this.destinationProperty().set(destination);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The button "add leg" does magic: the tableview focus border flashes and at some point you get a scrollbar. Probably you have to select something first. If you select row #2 and hit "Insert leg before", it inserts a row above, but focuses on the selected row and makes the 2nd column editable. If you click "Insert leg after" on the 1st table row, you get an exception. Showing a buggy example doesn't make my point invalid ;-)

Comment: As I said, I threw it together from scratch in 15 mins - about the limit I'm prepared to invest in an answer to a question that shows about 15 mins less code ;), so clearly it's likely to be buggy. The OP didn't specify anything about editing, which we all know is tricky - I just included that as a point to start from.  The point is the functionality he actually requested is easy, not unsupported as you claim. You're hijacking his actual question for a rant about the functionality you want, not the functionality he requested.

Comment: Sounds great, thanks. Since you're bothered by it, I modified my answer and deleted everything after the comma.